# Content-Type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' in request is changed to Content-Type: application/json; in Karate version 0.9.2

Tags: karate

When i send the  Content-Type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' as header it is changed to Content-Type: application/json; in Karate version 0.9.2 . 
In Karate version 0.7.0 it is sent as Content-Type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' only .

```
    Given url "https://foo.bar.buzz"
    And header Content-Type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    And form field username = "check"
    And form field password = "Password"
    And request {}
    And header Content-Type = 'application/json'
    When method POST
    Then status 200
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the 3rd last line you have the `header` set ?

And you should never use a `request` body for a form submit.

Try the below, it works fine:

```
Given url 'https://postman-echo.com/post'
And form field foo = 'bar'
When method post
```

Result:

```
1 > POST https://postman-echo.com/post
1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
1 > Content-Length: 7
1 > Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
1 > Host: postman-echo.com
1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/1.8.0_112)
foo=bar
```

Comment: My mistake . The content type of api was changed from application/json to application/x-www-form-urlencoded  recently . Forgot to remove the 3rd last line in my code .